# why does baked procedural texture look pixelated

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv, shaders

basically I have a procedural texture that is supposed to look like rust and I want to convert the procedural texture into an image based texture but my problem is the baked texture looks very blurry and not nearly as sharp here is a comparison[image]

[image]

I also have normal maps that I want to bake but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm not sure why the texture comes out blurry because I did bake the texture to 4096X4096. for baking I used the emission shader and I baked the image coming off the mix shader which goes into principled.
here is the blend file [image]

Answer (score 1):

There will always be a loss in quality when baking a shader to an image. The higher resolution the blank image you are baking to is, the better the resolution the texture appears. Try making the blank target image higher resolution.

Comment: I figured out the problem, it was because I set the samples to 1 for the bake which I read online should be fine for only an albedo texture but apparently it causes bad pixelization and setting it to 8 completely fixed this problem